# Select total of childrens in multiple tables in one query with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multiple-tables

All my afternoon was consumed trying to deal with a query (or two or three) in order to get the count of all childs of three tables. Take a look to my design:

user table

```
id_user | name
1 | foo
2 | bar
```

wons table

```
id_won | user
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
```

draws table

```
id_draw | user
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 2
```

loses table

```
id_lose | user
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
name | wons | draws | loses
foo | 2 | 1 | 3
bar | 1 | 2 | 0
```

This is my try:

```
select 
    u.name, w.total_w, d.total_d, l.total_l
from 
    user u
    LEFT JOIN 
    (select count(user) as total_w, user from wons group by user) as w
    ON w.user = u.id_user
    LEFT JOIN 
    (select count(user) as total_d, user from draws group by user) as d 
    ON d.user = w.user
    LEFT JOIN 
    (select count(user) as total_l, user from loses group by user) as l 
    ON d.user= .user

group by u.id_user;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.name, w.uw as wins, l.ul as loses, d.ud as draws from user
    left join (select user, COUNT(id_won) uw from wons group by user) w on w.user = u.user_id
    left join (select user, COUNT(id_lose) ul from loses group by user) l on l.user = u.user_id
    left join (select user, COUNT(id_draw) ud from draws group by user) d on d.user = u.user_id
```

This one would just the needed amount of work for the task.

Comment: Thank you so much @Francisco Soto, your query is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can calculated their total values in a subquery and joined them on table `users`. I added `COALESCE` to show `zero` instead of `null` in the case the `user` is not present on the other tables.

```
SELECT  a.id_user,
        COALESCE(b.totalWon,0) Wons,
        COALESCE(d.totalLoses,0) Loses,
        COALESCE(c.totalDraws,0) Draws
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT `user`, COUNT(id_won) totalWon
            FROM wons
            GROUP BY `user`
        ) b ON a.id_user = b.`user`
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT `user`, COUNT(id_draw) totalDraws
            FROM draws
            GROUP BY `user`
        ) c ON a.id_user = c.`user`
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT `user`, COUNT(id_lose) totalLoses
            FROM loses
            GROUP BY `user`
        ) d ON a.id_user = d.`user`
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99204/3)

Comment: I would suggest counting the id instead of using *. The reason is that if the tables has more fields (which it probably does) you don't need to pull the rest of the information from the table and you make your query more "indexable".

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    u.name,
    w.wins,
    d.draws,
    l.loses
FROM
    user u
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user,COUNT(*) wins FROM wons GROUP BY user) w ON w.user = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user,COUNT(*) draws FROM draws GROUP BY user) d ON d.user = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user,COUNT(*) loses FROM loses GROUP BY user) l ON l.user = u.id_user
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91b61/10

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest an alternative approach which might be an overkill for your project but keeps performance in mind if you are going to generate the desired result a lot.

Create a summary table (similar to your desired output). You can empty shell record created for each user there.

Add triggers in won, draw and losses table that simply updated the data in summary table.

That's one approach. Next approach is if your desired result isn't mission critical (i.e. does not have to be an up to date thing) then consider adding a scheduled events (that run every 10 or 20 min that run the query provided above (which I've given +1 votes) and use that to update the summary table.

Best of luck!

Comment: Well, I agree with you, but the current database can not be changed. Do a summary trigger will be awesome hehe :D